# Unable to find an image when inspecting using dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to download an image from a website and tried "right click + save image" however it was not possible. Then I inspected the site, but despite the image is there I'm unable to find it as a background-image, or as a  element.

What am I doing wrong?

The image is the first one that displays when opening this website:

https://fundacionintegra.org/beneficiarios/

Thanks.

Comment: It's the `<div>` with class "vc-row"; scroll the inspector down to the rule for `.vc-custom`

Comment:  https://fundacionintegra.org/wp-content/uploads/03_beneficiarios.jpg

Comment: BTW: you can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gallerify-powerful-image/hlmlhalegjopepcnfbnphmpobjkjhdgk/related?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can clearly see the image:
Its in the class:

```
vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid hero-slideshow-wrapper hero-slideshow-normal loaded vc_custom_1501845858579 vc_row-has-fill vc_row-o-content-middle vc_row-flex
```